# DocuSign API - Specify redirect URL after email signing ceremony is completed

Tags: docusignapi

I am creating an envelope that should be signed by a Signer using the email flow.

I would like the Signer to be redirected to a specific URL after they complete the signing session. How can I achieve this?

For the RecipientViewRequest (ie. for an embedded signing session), there is a ReturnURL that I can specify. I can't find a similar property to specify for the email flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post-signing landing pages aren't directly configurable through the API.

That said, those can be configured through your account's Branding: https://docs.docusign.com/supportdocs/ndse-admin-guide/Content/advanced-branding-configuration.htm#URLs

By setting `Go to Admin > Brand (Or Brands: Edit) > Destination URLs`, you can direct email signers to pages you control. If your account has multiple brands enabled, you can create multiple configurations and apply them to envelopes using the `brandId` parameter.

If you don't have Branding enabled on your account, you'll want to reach out to your Account Manager, or to the Sales team to discuss.